# Is it possible to get pointer to the 'this' structure, when using designated initializer?

Tags: c, initialization, designated-initializer

This kind of struct is used as head of linked list:

```
struct lista
{
    struct lista* next;
    struct lista* prev;
};
```

When next and prev both points to struct itself, then the list is empty.
The following macro can be used for initializing the structure:

```
#define LISTA_INIT_EMPTY(list) { .next = (list), .prev = (list) }
```

this way:

```
struct lista my_list = LISTA_INIT_EMPTY(&my_list);
```

But, is there any way to do same thing by the following way, without macro parameter?:

```
struct lista my_list = LISTA_INIT_EMPTY;
```

I tried the following, but it caused a compile error:

```
#define LISTA_INIT_EMPTY     { .next = &.next, .prev = &.next }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the only way I see is unpleasant:

```
#define LISTA_INIT_EMPTY     { .next = (&my_list), .prev = (&my_list) }
```

Not nice at all as it only works if your variable is called `my_list`. And there's no nice way as `this` does not exist in C.

Why not using `NULL` instead of pointing to "this"? If this is not satisfactory, keeping the parameterized macro is probably the best.

**EDIT:** (thanks to R's comment below, I finally understood the need):

As there no "this" and to only enter the name of the variable once, I suggest using such a macro:

```
#define CREATE_EMPTY_LISTA(name) struct lista name = { .next=&name, .prev=&name }
```

And later in the code:

```
CREATE_EMPTY_LISTA(my_list); // creates and initializez my_list at the same time
```

Comment: I think OP wants all lists, including the initial empty one, to be circular. This is not entirely unreasonable; often it eliminates all the ugly corner cases in your list handling functions.

Comment: `CREATE_EMPTY_LISTA` is basically the same as `LISTA_INIT_EMPTY` mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Yes, but with one important difference: `struct lista my_list = LISTA_INIT_EMPTY(&my_list);` forces you to repeat the name of the variable, which is not nice and quite error prone. `CREATE_EMPTY_LISTA(my_list);` allows you not repeating it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your list initialization technique is similar what's used in the Linux kernel source for their linked lists (`include/linux/list.h`).

For initialization of a list when the list head is declared, instead of trying to do something like:

```
// won't work:
struct lista my_list = /* something or other */;
```

Linux uses a macro that performs both the delcaration and the initialization (so the user still has to use the name only once). For your `struct lista` it might look like:

```
#define LISTA_HEAD struct lista name = LISTA_INIT_EMPTY(name)

// this is all the user needs to do to both declare and initialize a list:
LISTA_HEAD(my_list);
```

Take a look at `include/linux/list.h` for all the details.  There are also nice explanations of how the lists operations work (not all of it is intuitive):

- Linux Kernel Development, [Chapter 11.5, "Linked Lists"](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5)
- [Linux Kernel Linked List Explained](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) by Kulesh Shanmugasundaram

Answer (score 0):

Not really! If you define empty as NULL instead of "itself" then you could do it by:

`#define LISTA_INIT_EMPTY {NULL,NULL}`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible, since the block needs to know the instance.

Also `.next = &.next` will not work since the types do not match. (`struct lista*` to `struct lista**`)

Answer (score 0):

No, your initializer creates a `struct lista` and then assigns `my_list` to it. Your idea of a `this` does not make sense in this context, it wouldn't point to `my_list` until after it had been assigned.